# How to create an attribute node and attach it to output node..?

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0

I'm not able to figure out a way to attach an attribute node to output node in below scenario..

**input xml:**

```
<record>
    <user>
        <field name="LastName">user33</field>
        <field name="FirstName">user33</field>
        <field name="Title"/>
        <field name="Email">user33@gmail.com</field>
        <field name="WorkPhone"/>
        <field name="Fax"/>
        <field name="Description">new user</field>
        <field name="Group Member"> group1</field>
    </user>
</record>
```

**Expected output:**

```
<add class="user" id-val="user33 user33" >          
        <add-value attr="LastName">
            <value type="string">user33</value>
        </add-attr>
        <add-value attr="FirstName">
            <value type="string">user33</value>
        </add-value>
        <add-value attr="Email">
            <value type="string">user33@gamil.com</value>
        </add-value>
        <add-value attr="Description">
            <value type="string">new user</value>
        </add-value>
    </add>
```

this is the snippet of xslt that i have so far.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:variable name="lessThan" select="'&#x3C;'"/>
  <xsl:variable name="GreaterThan" select="'&#x3E;'"/>

  <xsl:template match="user">
    <xsl:variable name="temp1" select="concat(field[@name=$srcdn-field-name1],' ')"/>
    <xsl:variable name="temp2" select="concat($temp1,field[@name=$srcdn-field-name2])"/>
    <xsl:variable name="src" select="translate($temp2,'+=,.\','-----')"/>

    <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="$lessThan"/>
    <xsl:text>add</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="$GreaterThan"/>

    <!-- it is required to add attribute id-val to element <add> with value of  $src-->

    <xsl:for-each select="field[string()]">
      <xsl:variable name="fieldValue" select="normalize-space(.)"/>
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="@name !='Group Member'">
          <add-value attr="{@name}">
            <value type="string">
              <xsl:value-of select="$fieldValue"/>
            </value>
          </add-value>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="$lessThan"/>
          <xsl:text>/add</xsl:text>
          <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="$GreaterThan"/>

          <!--perform some other operations-->

        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Now my requirement is to have id-val and class as  attributes of `<add>`.. In this context the `<xsl:attribute>` isn't working. What changes do i need to make to my xslt.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't add an attribute to something that's not an element. That's one of the many reasons not to try to manually construct start and end tags. Try this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:template match="user">
    <xsl:variable name="temp1" select="concat(field[@name=$srcdn-field-name1],' ')"/>
    <xsl:variable name="temp2" select="concat($temp1,field[@name=$srcdn-field-name2])"/>
    <xsl:variable name="src" select="translate($temp2,'+=,.\','-----')"/>

    <add class="user" id-val="{$src}">

      <!-- it is required to add attribute id-val to element <add> with value of  $src-->

      <xsl:for-each select="field[string()]
                              [not((. | preceding-sibling::field)
                                             [@name = 'Group Member'])]">
        <add-value attr="{@name}">
          <value type="string">
            <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space()"/>
          </value>
        </add-value>
      </xsl:for-each>

    </add>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: First of all thanks for replying..With the  above suggested changes, **`<field name="Group Member"> group1</field>`** is also coming as part of my output,which is not expected..

Comment: Please try the above modification.

Comment: I replaced `preceding-sibling` with `self`in your previous submitted reply and it worked fine. I'll check with the latest modification that you have made.